# How to configure VSTS-agent in MAC?

Tags: azure-devops, macos-mojave

I'm having configure the VSTS in MAC.

[Downloading the agent to MACOSX Mojave](https://github.com/microsoft/azure-pipelines-agent/releases/tag/v2.152.0)

In terminal Running:

```
~/$ mkdir myagent && cd myagent
~/myagent$ tar zxvf ~/Downloads/vsts-agent-osx-x64-2.136.1.tar.gz
~/myagent$ ./config.sh
```

> Enter server URL > https://mercurio/ Enter authentication type (press
>   enter for Negotiate) > PAT Enter personal access token >
>   **************************************************** Connecting to server ... The handler does not support custom handling of
>   certificates with this combination of libcurl (7.54.0) and its SSL
>   backend ("LibreSSL/2.6.5"). Failed to connect.  Try again or ctrl-c to
>   quit

Comment: 'https://mercurio/' is not a valid server url. you should use the url of your AzureDevOps-Account (https://dev.azure.com/XXX or https://XXX.visualstudio.com, XXX is the name of your AzureDevOps)

Comment: Hi, Marconi. How about this issue now? Does it resolved now? If not, please let us to know the latest info about it.

Answer (score 0):

The error caused by your "`LibreSSL/2.6.5`".

`.NET CORE` is one necessary requirement about agent creation in MacOS, but `.NET Core` does not support LibreSSL at all, reference this doc: [agent System Prerequisites](https://github.com/microsoft/azure-pipelines-agent/blob/master/docs/start/envosx.md) . That's why you get this error message while you configuring agent in Mac.

Since .NET Core needs to use OpenSSL, so install and [build openSSL](http://foodpicky.com/?p=99) on your MacOS first. And then run the creation command again.